# How to get start and end of the week in swift?

Tags: swift, date, time

How to get start and end of the week in swift ?
this is my code

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
    }
}
```

i am calling like this

```
let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek
let endWeek = Date().endOfWeek
print(startWeek!)
print(endWeek!)
var dateFormat1 = DateFormatter()
dateFormat1.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy"
let startWeek2 = dateFormat1.string(from: startWeek!)
var dateFormat12 = DateFormatter()
dateFormat12.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yy"
let endWeek2 = dateFormat12.string(from: endWeek!)
print(startWeek2)
print(endWeek2)
```

and output

```
2017-09-24 18:30:00 +0000
2017-09-30 18:30:00 +0000
25-09-17
01-10-17
```

Comment: What is wrong? Please include a description of the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour as well, don't just show your current output...

Comment: see in my output,  after adding date formatter dates getting increse from 24-09-2017 to 25-09-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38260078/2303865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine. If you would run your code in a Playground, you could see the actual `Date` objects rather than there String representations. Even if you don't specify a `DateFormatter`, under the hood, when doing `print(Date())`, Swift uses a `DateFormatter` to print `Date` objects and hence that value will be a relative time instead of the absolute point in time provided by the `Date` object.

In a Playground you can see that the actual `startOfWeek` is `"Sep 25, 2017 at 12:00 AM"`, while the `endOfWeek` is `"Oct 1, 2017 at 12:00 AM"`, which are the correct values for the current week.

Don't use `print(Date())` for checking the correctness of `Date` objects, since as you can see, it will yield unexpected results due to the underlying `DateFormatter`s used.