# how to get year all weeks start date and end date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am making an application where I need to get the weeks of the year for all days in the current year. To achieve this, I am looking for a result similar to below

```
30 Dec - 05 Jan
06 Jan - 12 Jan
13 Jan - 19 Jan
.
.
.
28 Dec - 03 Jan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the suggested extension in this thread: [How to get start and end of the week in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402684/how-to-get-start-and-end-of-the-week-in-swift/46402722)
To iterate the weeks, and then just print the value with your desired formatter:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: Date())
let lastDayOfTheYear = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: currentYear, month: 12, day: 31))

var currentDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: currentYear, month: 1, day: 1))

while currentDate! < lastDayOfTheYear! {
    let startDay = currentDate!.startOfWeek!.formatted()
    let endDay = currentDate!.endOfWeek!.formatted()
    print("\(startDay) - \(endDay)")
    currentDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: currentDate!)
}

extension Date {
    func formatted() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
    
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
    }
}
```

prints:

```
December 30, 2019 - January 5, 2020
January 6, 2020 - January 12, 2020
...
December 21, 2020 - December 27, 2020
December 28, 2020 - January 3, 2021
```